# How to access specific elements in an array - angular template?

Tags: html, angular

currently i'm developing a webpage using angular - i have a class with 2 items as below:

```
Array(2)
 0: uiData { id: 12, price: 324 }
 1: uiData { id: 23, price: 432 }
```

i'm trying to access these data in angular template

```
<div *ngFor="let item of uiData">
    price: {{item.price}}
</div>
```

output:what i getting is as below

```
price: 324
price: 432
```

desired output i'm looking for is

```
price: 324/432
```

tried accessing the data by providing the index , like uiData[0].price/uiData[1].price but this isn't working.

is there a way to access these items?

Comment: What's the error in using: uiData[0].price/uiData[1].price?

Comment: The entire applications data points are zero, meaning displaying zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to access these data by reopen another {{}}

```
<div>
    price: {{uiData[0].price}}/{{uiData[1].price}}
</div>
```

If you don't want to access directly the data at range 0 and 1 you can also loop on array like that

```
<div>
    price: 
    <span *ngFor="let item of uiData;last as isLast">
      {{item.price}}
      <ng-container *ngIf="!isLast">/</ng-container>
   </span
</div>
```

Comment: you have a duplicate  "

Comment: @jeremy-denis: Thanks for the solution , the second option looping through the array solved my problem. The first option is displaying zero's in the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```
<div> price: <span *ngFor="let item of uiData;index as i">
    {{item.price}}
        <span *ngIf="i!=(uiData?.length-1)">/
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```